# Make calendar entry readonly

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I inserted a calender contract entry like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, name);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, getDisplayName(account));
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xffff0000);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, getMailAddressOf(account));
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").getDisplayName());
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
builder.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
builder.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true");
Uri result = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(builder.build(), values);
```

This works great, I can enter calender entries etc. But I need to make it now read only so that the user cannot edit the calendar entry.

I thought that when I set `CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL` to `CAL_ACCESS_READ` it should be enough to make the calendar read only.

Any idea how to achieve that? By the way I'm testing on a Pixel with Android O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't make the user to be the organizer**. When adding the event, the default organizer will be the user. To change it, add this line to the ContentValues when adding the event, assign an organizer email address like this

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,"an_organizer_name@gmail.com";
```

**Since the user is not the organizer, the user can still delete the event but not able to edit the event content such as time, title, description, etc.**

Well that took some time. In the end I found out that I have to change the mail address of the `CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER` value to prevent that I can edit the calender entry. Just as a hint for others how I sloved the problem I tried a lot of stupid things but then I had the idea to check how it is done in AOSP. So I just searched for *"calendar aosp code"* and found the code mirrowed on GitHub. After using the code search within the repo I found the method [`canModifyEvent(...)`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/2bbf7b8414ebcff2207b08224d8913241a766a5a/src/com/android/calendar/event/EditEventHelper.java#L1157). Now it became oblivious:

```
public static boolean canModifyEvent(CalendarEventModel model) {
    return canModifyCalendar(model)
            && (model.mIsOrganizer || model.mGuestsCanModify);
}
```

Make sure that the event cannot been edited by guests and by don't be the organizer.

Happy Coding!